# get child object property by variable

Tags: php

How to get an object's child object property by variable name?

```
echo $object->zip->name;  // this one gives "Budapest"
$field = 'zip->name';
echo $object->$field;  // this one gives null
```

I found many solutions using `$object->{$field}`, but it also does nor work

Comment: can you add what the object looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explode the name by `->` and then use followed method.

```
$object = new StdClass();
$object->zip->name = 'Test';


$field = 'zip->name';
$field_arr = explode('->', $field);
var_dump($object->{$field_arr[0]}->{$field_arr[1]});
```

**Output:**

```
string(4) "Test"
```

Hope this will help you.